# Resulting number of episodes_this_iter and timesteps_this_iter

Tags: flow-project

Running the stabilizing highway example and setting:

```
# time horizon of a single rollout
HORIZON = 750
# number of rollouts per training iteration
N_ROLLOUTS = 10
# number of parallel workers
N_CPUS = 1
```

I would expect it to run an number of N_ROLLOUTS episodes, each with HORIZON = 750 environment steps, and then train over the resulting 
config["train_batch_size"] = HORIZON * N_ROLLOUTS
samples, in this case 7500.
With the setting above, this roughly happens,and I get:

```
done: false
  episode_len_mean: 750.0
  episode_reward_max: 378.8144682438323
  episode_reward_mean: 371.58900412233226
  episode_reward_min: 363.96868303824317
  episodes_this_iter: 10
  episodes_total: 10
  experiment_id: 321488011dc74a4d9b8d4e45dd6245af
  hostname: fortiss-n-065
  info:
    default:
      cur_kl_coeff: 0.20000000298023224
      cur_lr: 4.999999873689376e-05
      entropy: 18.401643753051758
      kl: 0.018729193136096
      policy_loss: -0.035810235887765884
      total_loss: 172.8546600341797
      vf_explained_var: -0.01728551648557186
      vf_loss: 172.88673400878906
    grad_time_ms: 6208.281
    load_time_ms: 47.492
    num_steps_sampled: 7600
    num_steps_trained: 7600
    sample_time_ms: 139252.878
    update_time_ms: 451.736
  iterations_since_restore: 1
  node_ip: 192.168.17.165
  num_metric_batches_dropped: 0
  pid: 15759
  policy_reward_mean: {}
  time_since_restore: 146.0045006275177
  time_this_iter_s: 146.0045006275177
  time_total_s: 146.0045006275177
  timestamp: 1565803764
  timesteps_since_restore: 7600
  timesteps_this_iter: 7600
  timesteps_total: 7600
  training_iteration: 1
```

This is as I would expect it to be, except that 7600 instead of 7500 timesteps were performed. (3 Warmup steps x 10 would explain 30 additional steps).
But at least this is close to my expectation.

Now if I change the settings to:

```
# time horizon of a single rollout
HORIZON = 750
# number of rollouts per training iteration
N_ROLLOUTS = 50
# number of parallel workers
N_CPUS = 25
```

this is the result:

```
  done: false
  episode_len_mean: 750.0
  episode_reward_max: 390.90993664259395
  episode_reward_mean: 377.01513002372076
  episode_reward_min: 359.4016123285148
  episodes_this_iter: 38
  episodes_total: 38
  experiment_id: 1721602809bf409daff0891552be1cc6
  hostname: fortiss-n-065
  info:
    default:
      cur_kl_coeff: 0.20000001788139343
      cur_lr: 4.999999873689376e-05
      entropy: 18.317197799682617
      kl: 0.013906443491578102
      policy_loss: -0.014860117807984352
      total_loss: 169.02618408203125
      vf_explained_var: 0.006413168739527464
      vf_loss: 169.0382843017578
    grad_time_ms: 22726.94
    load_time_ms: 66.28
    num_steps_sampled: 37600
    num_steps_trained: 37600
    sample_time_ms: 224101.383
    update_time_ms: 1391.422
  iterations_since_restore: 1
  node_ip: 192.168.17.165
  num_metric_batches_dropped: 0
  pid: 13919
  policy_reward_mean: {}
  time_since_restore: 248.4277114868164
  time_this_iter_s: 248.4277114868164
  time_total_s: 248.4277114868164
  timestamp: 1565802831
  timesteps_since_restore: 37600
  timesteps_this_iter: 37600
  timesteps_total: 37600
  training_iteration: 1
```

Now this I cannot explain. I would have expcted:
episodes_this_iter: 50
timesteps_this_iter: = 750*50= 37500

Now again on timesteps there is a 100 offset and at least thats close to the expectation, but how can it be with episodes_this_iter: 38?

Then, I tried to setup a Muli-Agent environment for the highway scenario. With this, it looks as follows:

```
   # time horizon of a single rollout
   HORIZON = 750
   # number of rollouts per training iteration
   N_ROLLOUTS = 5
   # number of parallel workers
   N_CPUS = 1

   config["num_workers"] = N_CPUS
   config["train_batch_size"] = HORIZON * N_ROLLOUTS
```

resulting in:

```
done: false
  episode_len_mean: 748.0
  episode_reward_max: 1655.6750207800903
  episode_reward_mean: 1655.6750207800903
  episode_reward_min: 1655.6750207800903
  episodes_this_iter: 1
  episodes_total: 1
  experiment_id: 0757df140fe446f8af0bd7fbee0ba69b
  hostname: fortiss-n-065
  info:
    default:
      cur_kl_coeff: 0.20000000298023224
      cur_lr: 4.999999873689376e-05
      entropy: 1.397594690322876
      kl: 0.007053409703075886
      policy_loss: -0.0008417787030339241
      total_loss: 59.896278381347656
      vf_explained_var: 0.20434552431106567
      vf_loss: 59.89570617675781
    grad_time_ms: 2839.323
    load_time_ms: 45.883
    num_steps_sampled: 4222
    num_steps_trained: 4222
    sample_time_ms: 21399.539
    update_time_ms: 414.231
  iterations_since_restore: 1
  node_ip: 192.168.17.165
  num_metric_batches_dropped: 0
  pid: 23115
  policy_reward_mean: {}
  time_since_restore: 24.741214990615845
  time_this_iter_s: 24.741214990615845
  time_total_s: 24.741214990615845
  timestamp: 1565808435
  timesteps_since_restore: 4222
  timesteps_this_iter: 4222
  timesteps_total: 4222
  training_iteration: 1
```

What can be wrong here? I would have expected to always get

`episodes_this_iter = N_ROLLOUTS`
`timesteps_this_iter = train_batch_size = HORIZON * N_ROLLOUTS`

Comment: I had similar behaviour when running the example using ES. For example, with N_ROLLOUTS=2 / N_CPUS=2 --> episodes_this_iter = 4, but with 6 / 2, result was 8.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this seems like an RLlib oddity rather than anything to do with Flow? Sorry if that's not helpful, but they may be able to answer this question better.